# How to aggregate exchanges without restrictions

Tags: apache-camel, restrictions, aggregator, filesplitting

We have current situation. I use Apache Camel, split large file for small exchanges (using splitter, see below) and validate them. Then I need aggregate messages, but I use aggregator and it requires setup complition size or another. Can I aggragate all exchanges from current document without setting restrictions?

My Route:

```
 from("file:data?noop=true?move={{package.success}}&moveFailed={{package.failed}}")
                .transacted()
                .split(ExpressionBuilder.beanExpression(new InvoiceIteratorFactory(), "createIterator"))
                .streaming()
                .process(new ValidatorProcessor())
                .choice()
                .when(new Predicate() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
                        return exchange.getContext().getProperty(ValidatorProcessor.STATE_PROPERTY).equals(ValidatorProcessor.STATE_SUCCESS);
                    }
                })
                .to("jpa:/...")
                .otherwise()
                .aggregate(body(String.class), new MyAggregationStrategy()).completionSize(????)
                .to("smtps://smtp.gmail.com?username={{remote.e-mail}}&password={{remote.password}}");
```

To set aggregator I use to set count of exchanges or time, but I don't know how many exchanges will be.

Comment: I suggest you to slow down, and write a longer question about what you want to do and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So splitter EIP in Camel generates a header called `CamelSplitComplete` every time it finishes splitting an exchange. This header is a boolean value.

What I would do is use `completionPredicate()` in the aggregator instead of `completionSize()`. So whenever that header is true it will finish aggregating:

```
from("file:data?noop=true?move={{package.success}}&moveFailed={{package.failed}}")
    .transacted()
    .split(ExpressionBuilder.beanExpression(new InvoiceIteratorFactory(), "createIterator"))
    .streaming()
    .process(new ValidatorProcessor())
    .choice()
    .when(new Predicate() {
                @Override
                public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
                    return exchange.getContext().getProperty(ValidatorProcessor.STATE_PROPERTY).equals(ValidatorProcessor.STATE_SUCCESS);
                }
            })
     .to("jpa:/...")
     .otherwise()
     .aggregate(body(String.class), new MyAggregationStrategy()).completionPredicate(header("CamelSplitComplete") == true)
     .to("smtps://smtp.gmail.com?username={{remote.e-mail}}&password={{remote.password}}");
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it. But I have one more question. As you see in route, app read file, save to DB entities that were parsed well, and if there was a mistake,  it aggregates messages with those mistakes and then send it to e-mail. I have such question, how to rollback all those entities that was commited to DB during parsing current file?